# Syntax errors when using multiple end as statements in Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas, syntax-error

I am using the proc SQL code below to assign values to and create variables with names that end in _val. Some of the variable names are too long after adding _val so I attempted to use a do loop and %if %then %else to conditionally shorten the names.

```
%macro rn_do;
proc sql noprint;
    create table validate_select2 as
    select *
    %do a=1 %to &checkbox_select_n;
        %do b=1 %to %eval(&&variable_checkbox_select_max&a);
            ,case when &b=1 and &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b. in (select valid_values from response_options_scan where variable="&&variable_checkbox_select&a") then "&&variable_checkbox_select&a&&b valid value"
            when &b=1 and &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b.="" and (select requirement_status from response_options_select where variable="&&variable_checkbox_select&a") in ("All Records (Backend data)","All Records", "Required") then "&&variable_checkbox_select&a&&b invalid value: missing"
            when &b=1 and &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b.="" and (select requirement_status from response_options_select where variable="&&variable_checkbox_select&a") then "&&variable_checkbox_select&a&&b invalid value: missing"
            when &b=1 and &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b.="" then "&&variable_checkbox_select&a&&b valid value: missing"
            when &b ne 1 and &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b.="" then "&&variable_checkbox_select&a&&b valid value: missing"
            when &b ne 1 and strip(&&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b.) in (select valid_values from response_options_scan where variable="&&variable_checkbox_select&a") then "&&variable_checkbox_select&a&&b valid value"
            else "&&variable_checkbox_select&a&&b invalid value"
            %do c=1 %to 3;
                %if &&variable_checkbox_select&a=child&c._coadministered_vaccine %then %do;
                    end as child&c._coadministered_vax&b._val format=$100.
                %end;
                %else %if &&variable_checkbox_select&a=coadministered_vaccine_other %then %do;
                    end as coadministered_vax_other&b._val format=$100.
                %end;
                %else %do;
                    end as &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b._val format=$100.
                %end;
            %end;
        %end;
    %end;
    from validate_select;
quit;
%mend rn_do;

%rn_do;
```

I am getting the following errors in the log. SAS seems to be taking issue with my final end as statement but I have no idea why.

```
 NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "RN_DO".
 169               end as &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b._val format=$100.
                   ___
                   22
 NOTE 137-205: Line generated by the invoked macro "RN_DO".
 169               end as &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b._val format=$100.
                                                                ______
                                                                22
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ',', AS, FROM.  
 
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: GROUP, HAVING, ORDER, WHERE.  
 
 NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "RN_DO".
 169               end as &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b._val format=$100.
                                                                ______
                                                                76
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Comment: Arrays an option here at all instead of SQL?

Comment: What purpose does the %DO C loop serve?  It cannot work as written since it generates three END keywords for the single CASE keyword.  If you want to generates three different variables then the %DO C statement needs to be before the CASE clause starts.

Comment: Show the SAS code you want the macro to generate.

Comment: you do not explain what the macro variables being referenced mean nor what types of values they have.  It is very strange to have macro that is using macro variables that are neither input nor local nor even have any comments explaining where they are expected to have come from.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite tell what you're doing, but I think the problem is you have a `%DO  c=1 to 3;` loop which is generating 3 end statements.  So the first one may be valid, but the next two are errors.

```
        %do c=1 %to 3;
            %if &&variable_checkbox_select&a=child&c._coadministered_vaccine %then %do;
                end as child&c._coadministered_vax&b._val format=$100.
            %end;
            %else %if &&variable_checkbox_select&a=coadministered_vaccine_other %then %do;
                end as coadministered_vax_other&b._val format=$100.
            %end;
            %else %do;
                end as &&variable_checkbox_select&a.&&b._val format=$100.
            %end;
        %end;
```

Perhaps you just need to get rid of that %DO loop. But that may be wrong, as I can't see the big picture.

If you run the code with options MPRINT turned on (I **always** have this turned on) it will show the generated code, should help you see if 3 `end` statements are being generated, as I suspect.

Comment: I ran the code with MPRINT on and it was indeed generating 3 end statements. Taking out the do loop does solve the problem, but still wondering if I can accomplish the same thing without adding the additional %else %if statements.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell enough of about the value of each macro variable to suggest how to get rid of the %IF/%ELSE block to generate the END statement.  You may be better off posting a new question where you give a small example of the data, your purpose, and your current approach (maybe without a macro, just a SQL step).  It's possible there are easier DATA step approaches.